# Tracking player on "overview map"

Tags: unity, shaders, camera, maps

I'm working on a city-based isometric game where the player controls a character moving around in the city.

I need to create both an overview map and a minimap similar to both GTA and Mafia 3. Here's a good example:
https://youtu.be/0Jfgjt_1JFg?t=1437 (timestamp)

My question is:
How would you implement such a map? My best guess is to have another camera present a simplified city by switching out material or manipulating with shaders. Another idea was to simple have the map as a drawn image and then "manually" track the player.

Really looking forward to hear you solution!

Comment: It sounds like you have two viable solutions in mind already. How have you tried putting these ideas into practice? Did you get stuck with any particular aspect that we can help you with?

Comment: I definitely have, but I'm afraid of overlooking a smarter or more clean approach. I'm still new to Unity and I worry that I'm not using the right tools.

Comment: I'd say you've covered the main options. I'd only spend time exploring something more exotic if you find a concrete reason that the obvious approaches above don't serve your needs. Have confidence in your skills as a game developer: if you think it could possibly work, you can probably make it work!